# Which ai service should I use in for my own ai raspberry pi project? And what are the best sources for learning to build an AI in raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I want to start a AI project in raspberry pi as a hobby. I want to develop my own modules and in my own language.

After a short research I found different services that compatible with raspberry Pi. And I decided it would be very useful to start with a library and make changes and additions into that library. However I cant decide which service should I use.

Basically I want to develop that AI in my own language and I want to full control in source code, so I can make changes freely.

Also I want to have ability to export all my own modules for future If I want to change the platform of AI. So somehow the codes that I will write should be compatible for general devices.

I dont have very deep knowledge in CS. But I thought it would be a nice hobby for me. As a start I found a begginer book which is Programming Collective Intelligence by Toby Segaran.

I am open for all guidance about this project.

The services that I found for rapsberry pi are:

wit.ai

api.ai (It is not directly says that its compatible with rPi. But It has python   support)

jasper

These are the suitable services that I found for rapsberry Pi. You can suggest anything related to that topic.

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion going on in your question. You're asking about AI platforms, but you've linked to 3 natural language processing platforms. Those are different things - AI platforms generally exploit machine learning to expedite problem solving, while natural language processing platforms parse spoken words into strings and carry out actions based on the strings. I'm not sure the question's answerable in its current form.

Comment: OK you are right. I may have definition errors. From your comment I can say that I want to start with a natural language processing and build my own AI with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to sit back and actually do more research. It seems that you don't quite know what you want to do, or don't know how to ask. This isn't a bad thing, it just seems that you are a little confused. Instead of just diving deep right into a larger project, maybe making smaller projects and moving on is a better bet? While NLP and AI are related, trying to accomplish a project using both with no prior knowledge is probably not a good idea. You could easily start the project and barely touch on one topic because the other is so large. Neither of those topics are generally for people that aren't more advanced in CS.

That being said, I think you should look into NLP at a more basic level and understand what you are doing. Then move on to more advanced functions. If you want your project to learn (maybe the A.I you are thinking of) while you start on your NLP you should read a lot more. When I had my A.I class, we actually went over what knowledge looks like in a program. That may seem like a simple task, but It really isn't. The representation of knowledge and learning in an Object Oriented way is a little tough to get the hang of. Your agent (Project/A.I./NLP) will need to have some form of understanding of how to interact with information and what to do with it as well as use it at a later point in time. Then you need to make a decision if it is to be autonomous. If it is, how will it know if it's learning correctly and saving the correct information? If it's not autonomous, then are you going to be around to make sure the information is correct, stored and retrieved properly? What happens if you need to adjust code? If the information isn't stored correctly or something happens to the information depending on how you stored it, it could be lost.

So to actually answer your question based on what I wrote above, for learning purposes make your own. As far as good resources:
Artificial Intelligence: A Beginner’s Guide, Blay Whitby, OneWorld Publications, 2003

Artificial Intelligence: A System’s Approach, M. Tim Jones, Jones & Bartlett, 2009

The better of the 2 is Artificial Intelligence: A System's approach.

Comment: Good answer.  Close to a decade ago I can remember a (supposedly) 13-14 year old kid (I believe he really was that young) on a C forum stubbornly plowing ahead with implementing [perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) -- and, after weeks of politely bugging whoever would listen, having some success.  I wonder where that kid is now, lol?  Anyway, so there's another suggestion about somewhere to start with AI that anyone capable of writing code at a basic level should be able to get into.